# Displaying only a part of a line in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a line of data. It contains both words and numbers.It is

```
    15 F= -.33052537E+03 E0= -.33051414E+03 d E=.720942E-05 mag=24.6037:3
```

I need to extract the value -.33052537E+03 from this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `bash`

```
$ read one two three rest <<<'   15 F= -.33052537E+03 E0= -.33051414E+03 d E=.720942E-05 mag=24.6037:3'
$ echo "$three"
-.33052537E+03
```

#### Using `awk` and `bash`:

```
$ awk '{print $3}' <<<'   15 F= -.33052537E+03 E0= -.33051414E+03 d E=.720942E-05 mag=24.6037:3'
-.33052537E+03
```

#### Using `sed` and `bash`:

```
$ sed 's/.*F= //; s/ E0=.*//' <<<'   15 F= -.33052537E+03 E0= -.33051414E+03 d E=.720942E-05 mag=24.6037:3'
-.33052537E+03
```

#### Using GNU `grep` and `bash`:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=F= ).*(?= E0=)' <<<'   15 F= -.33052537E+03 E0= -.33051414E+03 d E=.720942E-05 mag=24.6037:3'
-.33052537E+03
```

Answer (score 0):

If only single line is there, then assign this line to a variable.

```
var="15 F= -.33052537E+03 E0= -.33051414E+03 d E=.720942E-05 mag=24.6037:3"

echo $var|awk '{print $3}'
```

If many lines are there, then insert those lines in a file, then

```
awk '{print $3}' file.txt
```